# tickets between two dates and two times

Tags: php

I have another question.

I get stuck by showing the tickets between two dates and two times.

I have following table fields:

Start date || ticketSDate,   Start time || ticketSTime

End date  || ticketEDate,   End time  || ticketETime

I want to show all the tickets where the End Date  and End Time are bigger or equal as now 
AND
Where the Start Date is less or equal as now

Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks, Benny

```
            <?php 

                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE  ticketEDate >= NOW() AND ticketETime > NOW() AND ticketSDate <= NOW()  ORDER by ticketSDate ASC");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))  { 



                        echo '<tr>
                                <td><h8>'. $row['ticketName'] .'</h8></td><br>

                                <td><h4><strong>Begin:</strong> &nbsp; ',date("d.m.Y", strtotime ($row['ticketSDate'])),' &nbsp; ', date('H:i', strtotime ($row['ticketSTime'])).' hr.<h4></td>
                                <td><h4><strong>Einde:</strong> &nbsp; ',date("d.m.Y", strtotime ($row['ticketEDate'])),' &nbsp; ', date('H:i', strtotime ($row['ticketETime'])).' hr.<h4></td>
                                <td><h4>'. $row['ticketDescription'] .'</h4></td>
                                <td><h4>'. $row['ticketID'] .'  <input name="book" type="button" value="Koop een ticket" /></h4></td>
                                <br><br>
                            </tr>';
                    }

            ?>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Please make your question more clear so we can focus our answer better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a flawed concept of thinking about `time`. You're saying

> I want to show all the tickets where the End Date and End Time are bigger

So that means on a date which is after today but time is still not what it is right now, return false which is not reasonable at all.

So you have to use some grouped conditions. For example, End datetime is greater than now.

Now if the end date is greater than today, forget about time its meaningless.

```
WHERE ticketEDate > NOW() OR (ticketEDate = NOW() AND ticketETime > NOW())
```

Same concept for the start.

A very simple and better solution would be to store the date time as one field and then your query is a very simple one.

Comment: Hey Hanky Panky, Thank you for your answer! 

I have converted the dates and times into one field, in the database, now it is stored like 2016-05-22 19:00:00, much eisier!

I have used:  SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE  EVerkoop > NOW()  AND  SVerkoop <= NOW()  ORDER by SVerkoop ASC   Thanks again